# Minimal bridging sets in infinite connected graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Let $G=(V, E)$ be a connected, simple, undirected graph. We say that $B\subseteq V$ is a *bridging set* if $B\neq V$ and removing $B$ makes the graph disconnected, or more formally: $$G \setminus B := (V\setminus B\;, \; \{e\in E: e\cap B = \varnothing\})$$ is not connected any more.

Is there an infinite connected graph $G=(V,E)$ such that for every bridging set $B\subseteq V$ there is a bridging set $B_1$ with $B_1\subseteq B$ and $B_1\neq B$?

Comment: formally an infinite complete graph satisfies the required property (it does not have bridging sets), but this is probably not what you mean?

Comment: It seems like the answer should surely be no by Zorn's lemma, but a proof that chains are bounded below didn't immediately come to me.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Perhaps the definition should be conceptually simplified by removing the unwarranted condition $B\ne V$. Then every graph does have at least one bridging set, namely $V$ (keeping in mind that the empty graph is not connected, as its number of components is $0$ rather than $1$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Take for $V = S \coprod T$ with bijections $s : \mathbb N \to S$ and $t : \mathbb N \to T$ ; and have the edge set $K_T \cup \{(s(i),t(j)) \quad\mathtt{ iff }\quad i \le j\}$.

[image: Graph awful drawing]

First, see that $\forall n$, $t(\mathbb N + n)$ is a bridging set. Indeed, $s(k)$ for $k \ge n$ is isolated. This gives an infinite strict chain of bridging sets, whose limit is empty (so not a bridging set).

Let $B$ be a bridging set. Let's prove that $B \supset t(\mathbb N + k)$ for a $k$. Suppose it's not the case, that is : $\forall k \in \mathbb N, \exists N(k), t(N(k)) \notin B$. Then take two nodes $u,v$, those nodes are in $T \cup s(\mathbb N + n)$, so both have $t(N(n))$ as a neighbourg.

Comment: To construct this, I had to first realize that in any solution, every bridging set must :
- Be infinite
- Cut the graph in infinite number of connected component
This didn't leave much choice, and after trying to prove this was impossible, well...

Comment: Nice!  For reference purposes, this is sometimes called the (infinite) Half Graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_graph.

Comment: @PaulMcKenney The Half graph does not have the clique on $T$, though.

Comment: Fantastic construction, thanks Hugo!